# Converting .txt file to Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to convert a .txt file like this to a Python dictionary:

```
18.10.2021       List Display                                                    
-----------------------------
 Selected Documents:        3
-----------------------------
|  Document|Description |Lng|
-----------------------------
|  VLX82304|Unit 523435 |EN |
|  VLX82340|Self  339304|EN |
|  VLX98234|Can  522018 |EN |
-----------------------------
```

I'd like to create a dictionary like so:

```
MyDict = {
"Document": "VLX82304", "VLX82340", "VLX98234",
"Description":  "Unit 523435", "Self  339304", "Can  522018"
[...] }
```

I have the following:

```
fileInfo = {"Document", "Description", "Lng"}

# > CLEANING UP .txt FILE 

LocalFile_LINES = []      # list to store file lines
# Read file
with open(".txt", 'r') as fp:
    # read an store all lines into list
    LocalFile_LINES = fp.readlines()
    NumLines = len(LocalFile_LINES)

# Write file
with open("CLEANED.txt", 'w') as fp:
    # iterate each line
    for number, line in enumerate(LocalFile_LINES):
        # delete line 5 and 8. or pass any Nth line you want to remove
        if number not in [0,1,2,3,4,5,NumLines-1, NumLines]:
            # The "NumLines-1" removes the actual "------", whereas NuMLines removes a space at the end
            fp.write(line)

# Getting num lines of newly CLEANED .txt file
txtCLEANED = open("CLEANED.txt", "r")
NumLines_CLEANED = txtCLEANED.readlines()
CLEANED_len = len(NumLines_CLEANED)
listIndex = list( range(0,CLEANED_len-1) )    # Creates a series of numbers 


# > CONVERTED.CLEANED.txt FILE TO PY DICT

Delimited = []
with open("CLEANED.txt", 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        Delimited = line.split("|")
        newItem = str( Delimited[1] )
        fileInfo["Document"].append( newItem )
```

but then I get an error at the very last line saying "TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable" when it should be a list ...

Could anyone please provide any input on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: To write a list, use `[]`, not `{}`. `fileInfo` currently is a set. But also a list you cannot access like `SKUfileInfo["Document"]`. Maybe you wanted to write a dictionary? But it's not clear to me.

Comment: Please provide text  (rather than an image) of the sample file contents

Comment: I'm now thinking that you wanted to initialize `fileInfo = {"Document": [], "Description": [], "Lng": []}`.

Comment: That's not a valid dict. Do you mean `{"Document": ["VLX82304", "VLX82340", "VLX98234"], "Description":  ["Unit 523435", "Self  339304", "Can  522018"], [...] }` (I wrapped values in `[]`)? If so, _why?_

Comment: Sorry I'm still new-ish at coding. I edited my post. You're both correct, mkrieger1 and Chris!
Chris, it's so that I can call to those values to put them into an OCR for some automation that I'm doing. I.e., I want to be able to call that value into a OCR function I made to click on it.

Comment: rv.kvetch, I'll upload the text onto the post

Comment: upload your full dataset please. this partial dataset is not gonna be very helpful. you can add it as text or as file (if the there is too much stuff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (or something like this) should work for this use case. Note that I used a string instead of reading from a file, as it's a bit easier to test with.

```py
from pprint import pprint


file_contents = """
18.10.2021       List Display
-----------------------------
 Selected Documents:        3
-----------------------------
|  Document|Description |Lng|
-----------------------------
|  VLX82304|Unit 523435 |EN |
|  VLX82340|Self  339304|EN |
|  VLX98234|Can  522018 |EN |
-----------------------------
""".strip()

_, col_headers, cols, _ = file_contents.rsplit('-----------------------------', 3)
col_headers = [h.strip() for h in col_headers.strip('\n|').split('|')]
cols = [line.strip(' |').split('|') for line in cols.strip().split('\n')]

my_dict = dict(zip(col_headers, zip(*cols)))

pprint(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Description': ('Unit 523435 ', 'Self  339304', 'Can  522018 '),
 'Document': ('VLX82304', 'VLX82340', 'VLX98234'),
 'Lng': ('EN', 'EN', 'EN')}
```

---

*NB: if you have an a text file and want to read the string contents, you can do it like below.*

```py
with open('my_file.txt') as in_file:
    file_contents = in_file.read()

# file_contents should now be a string with the contents of the file
```

Comment: this looks like it works great, but unfortunately I have to use the .txt file because the .txt will constantly be changing

Comment: Yep, it should be a similar approach with a text file. You'd just need to read in the contents of the file, but I think it should be the same.

Comment: Hi, I just tried it by reworking "file_contents" to be "file_contents = open('.txt', 'r')", 
but since it's not a string the .rsplit() method doesn't work. Using the above makes "file_contents" into type '_io.TextIOWrapper', NOT a string.

Comment: I guess I could force it into a string, but I'm not sure how it would turn out ... would it be uniform?

Comment: @MontX I updated the answer above with an example of how you would read in the file contents as a string

Comment: Ohh I understand what you did now! Thank you very much :)

Comment: No problem! glad that it was helpful for this use case.